# ggplot2 change legend title in this particular example

Tags: r, ggplot2, title, legend

I have tried many suggestions but none fit this particular simple example. How would I change the legend title to Sample?

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Order = c(1,1,2,2),
  Tissue = c("Bladder","Pancreas","Bladder","Pancreas"),
  Sample = c("WT","WT","Mutant","Mutant"),
  Percent = c(94.12,55,5.88,45)
)

ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = Tissue, y = Percent, group = Sample)) + 
    geom_point(aes(shape=reorder(Sample,Order), fill=reorder(Sample,Order)), size = 6) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("deepskyblue1","yellow"))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `scale_XX` accept a `name` argument that you can adjust:

```
scale_shape_manual(name = "Sample", values=c(21,22)) +
scale_fill_manual(name = "Sample", values=c("deepskyblue1","yellow"))
```

If you don't pass it into both scales, it creates two separate legends by default apparently.

You could alternatively do the `reoder()` bit before passing into your plotting code.

See [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_manual.html) for details.

Comment: Well I'll be. I had tried putting that in each scale line but not both.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to use `guides`

```
bp + guides(fill=guide_legend("Sample"),shape=guide_legend("Sample"))
```

[image]